# boost::spirit::qi matches[] trouble

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I have the trouble with parsing on my project. At least I found the minimum code sample on which the problem appears. So at now tries to parse the string

> "bool func1; const bool func2;"

Here the minimum sample code:

```
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
using qi::lexeme;
using qi::string;
typedef boost::spirit::ascii::space_type TSkipper;

struct MyField
{
    bool isConst;
    std::string mtype;
    std::string name;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT
    (
    MyField,
    (bool, isConst)
    (std::string, mtype)
    (std::string, name)
    )

void SpiritTestSimple()
{
    qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, std::string(), TSkipper> valid_symbols;
    qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, MyField(), TSkipper> field;

    valid_symbols %= lexeme[*qi::char_("a-zA-Z")];

    field %= qi::matches[string("const")] >> valid_symbols >> valid_symbols;

    std::string data = "aaa aaaa; const bbb bbbb;";

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    std::string::const_iterator first = data.begin(), last = data.end();
    std::list<MyField> parsed_vals;
    bool is_parsed;
    try
    {
        is_parsed = qi::phrase_parse(   first, last,  
                                        +(field > ';'), 
                                        boost::spirit::ascii::space, parsed_vals);
    }
    catch(const qi::expectation_failure<std::string::const_iterator>& e)
    {
        std::string frag(e.first, e.last);
        std::cout << e.what() << "'" << frag << "'" << std::endl;
    }

    BOOST_ASSERT(is_parsed && "the example not parsed");
}
```

I wrote

```
+(field > ';')
```

because in my project this block can be absent. And each function declaration must be ended by ';'. When the above code sample runs I see that raised exception and in the console appeared record:

```
boost::spirit::qi::expectation_failure''
```

As I understand right - after last semicolon the parser tries parse the next field rule and it parsed the "matches" (because it return value in any case) but the next parse of the valid_symbols is failed because after the last semicolon there are no data. So parsing fails.

How to avoid the parse fails in my case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest problem is with

```
valid_symbols = qi::lexeme[*qi::char_("a-zA-Z")];
```

The trouble here is that it can match the empty string. So the whole production for "field" can be an empty string. If you change it to (using `qi::alpha` as a shorthand):

```
valid_symbols = qi::lexeme[+qi::alpha];
```

You will find it does parse the input correctly.

Further notes:

- when you say *"I wrote `+(field > ';')` because in my project this block can be absent"* that seems contradictory to me. If you wanted to make the whole block optional, you'd write

  ```
  *(field > ';')
  ```

  or if you would want to repeated `;;` I'd expect

  ```
  *(-field > ';')
  ```

  (or perhaps `+(-field > ';')`).
- you will want to learn to use `BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG` to pinpoint your problems on your own

See the complete working example for demonstration of how to use spirit builtin debug capabilities: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75084ce0f566b7c9)**

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
typedef boost::spirit::ascii::space_type TSkipper;

struct MyField
{
    bool isConst;
    std::string mtype;
    std::string name;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT
    (
     MyField,
     (bool, isConst)
     (std::string, mtype)
     (std::string, name)
    )

template <typename It, typename TSkipper = boost::spirit::ascii::space_type>
struct MyGrammar : qi::grammar<It, std::list<MyField>(), TSkipper>
{
    MyGrammar() : MyGrammar::base_type(start) {
        valid_symbols = qi::lexeme[+qi::alpha];
        field         = qi::matches[qi::string("const")] >> valid_symbols >> valid_symbols;
        start         = +(field > ";");

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((valid_symbols)(field)(start))
    }
  private:
    qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, std::string(),        TSkipper> valid_symbols;
    qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, MyField(),            TSkipper> field;
    qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, std::list<MyField>(), TSkipper> start;
};

int main()
{
    std::string const data = "aaa aaaa; const bbb bbbb;";

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    std::string::const_iterator first = data.begin(), last = data.end();
    std::list<MyField> parsed_vals;

    bool is_parsed = false;

    try
    {
        MyGrammar<std::string::const_iterator> grammar;

        is_parsed = qi::phrase_parse(   first, last,  
                                        grammar, 
                                        boost::spirit::ascii::space, 
                                        parsed_vals);
    }
    catch(const qi::expectation_failure<std::string::const_iterator>& e)
    {
        std::string frag(e.first, e.last);
        std::cout << "Expectation failure: " << e.what() << " at '" << frag << "'" << std::endl;
    }

    BOOST_ASSERT(is_parsed && "the example not parsed");
}
```

Which prints:

```
<start>
<try>aaa aaaa; const bbb </try>
<field>
    <try>aaa aaaa; const bbb </try>
    <valid_symbols>
    <try>aaa aaaa; const bbb </try>
    <success> aaaa; const bbb bbb</success>
    <attributes>[[a, a, a]]</attributes>
    </valid_symbols>
    <valid_symbols>
    <try> aaaa; const bbb bbb</try>
    <success>; const bbb bbbb;</success>
    <attributes>[[a, a, a, a]]</attributes>
    </valid_symbols>
    <success>; const bbb bbbb;</success>
    <attributes>[[0, [a, a, a], [a, a, a, a]]]</attributes>
</field>
<field>
    <try> const bbb bbbb;</try>
    <valid_symbols>
    <try> bbb bbbb;</try>
    <success> bbbb;</success>
    <attributes>[[b, b, b]]</attributes>
    </valid_symbols>
    <valid_symbols>
    <try> bbbb;</try>
    <success>;</success>
    <attributes>[[b, b, b, b]]</attributes>
    </valid_symbols>
    <success>;</success>
    <attributes>[[1, [b, b, b], [b, b, b, b]]]</attributes>
</field>
<field>
    <try></try>
    <valid_symbols>
    <try></try>
    <fail/>
    </valid_symbols>
    <fail/>
</field>
<success></success>
<attributes>[[[0, [a, a, a], [a, a, a, a]], [1, [b, b, b], [b, b, b, b]]]]</attributes>
</start>
```

Comment: PS. You can write `qi::matches["const"]` directly there